# Divide legend in two columns ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, scatter-plot

I have the following table:

```
Sample  UMAP1   UMAP2   colors  tissue
C_A1    1.41771557752425    1.22200433730937    yellow2 Urine
C_A2    1.76055361418532    1.34108703383903    yellow2 Urine
C_A3    0.00750224109526362 2.73864657429924    yellow2 Urine
C_A4    1.6500702891979 1.08443364179582    yellow2 Urine
C_A5    1.47433412636331    1.24338667538958    yellow2 Urine
C_A9    1.81676319795816    1.41560757063772    yellow2 Urine
C_B1    1.58085792476313    1.06578750509132    yellow2 Urine
C_B2    0.54619869458667    1.47703917280933    yellow2 Urine
CKD_C1  1.77876535894167    2.1866355905902 yellow2 Urine
CKD_C2  1.5528582393691 1.56720266537748    yellow2 Urine
CKD_C3  0.00527727382088514 2.62619847720534    yellow2 Urine
CKD_C4  0.586308172828281   2.7784840588712 yellow2 Urine
CKD_C5  0.186228467054963   2.6796009437192 yellow2 Urine
PYL_E1  -3.07772498762527   4.45095110253223    yellow2 Urine
PYL_E2  1.1175301960485 1.06349707623584    yellow2 Urine
PYL_E3  1.82042047858787    1.42547383706531    yellow2 Urine
PYL_E4  1.66009595777039    1.72432475907437    yellow2 Urine
PYL_E5  1.13056114256336    1.13760951795915    yellow2 Urine
PYL_E6  1.79463825137017    1.47814506344302    yellow2 Urine
PYL_E7  0.622690635767324   -1.96794491349824   yellow2 Urine
PYL_E8  0.63118627267307    1.29871116070517    yellow2 Urine
PYL_E9  -4.58033059073059   3.96133161881786    yellow2 Urine
PYL_F1  1.51666575038286    1.59237710006909    yellow2 Urine
UO_D1   0.709257524588014   1.24974065107936    yellow2 Urine
UO_D2   1.69833621648934    2.18100899996296    yellow2 Urine
UO_D3   1.01987315310411    1.08349161107457    yellow2 Urine
UO_D4   1.53357549894633    1.46876538726954    yellow2 Urine
UO_D5   0.618372187901223   1.1600432701727 yellow2 Urine
UO_D6   1.80740300575174    1.93028754079873    yellow2 Urine
UO_D7   -1.90935774520858   2.21114064992169    yellow2 Urine
SBU_G1  0.0684949931212032  2.6323213276562 yellow2 Urine
SBU_G2  1.37378744895387    1.15990665575179    yellow2 Urine
SBU_G3  0.681350048991714   1.29504193314325    yellow2 Urine
SBU_G4  0.585511550079965   1.46021542902406    yellow2 Urine
SBU_G5  2.13609698314454    -1.52225184779846   yellow2 Urine
BR1.RPM -3.28586643197682   3.74476178876053    darkgrey    Brain
BR2.RPM -3.66581644761413   3.78800081614875    darkgrey    Brain
BR3.RPM -3.96475462680686   3.8275429988704 darkgrey    Brain
BR4.RPM -3.6558646156002    3.90023979275899    darkgrey    Brain
BR5.RPM -3.77917418926683   3.65892915155001    darkgrey    Brain
CO1.RPM 1.19249345974165    -1.0914160958934    forestgreen Colon
CO2.RPM 0.853658643619059   -0.658496441780366  forestgreen Colon
CO3.RPM 0.975760223303845   -1.28665248361392   forestgreen Colon
CO5.RPM 1.36511790751794    -2.13567084452923   forestgreen Colon
DU1.RPM 1.63592949492624    -2.46405219183458   olivedrab4  Duodenum
DU2.RPM 1.87925711931471    -3.03633498025664   olivedrab4  Duodenum
DU5.RPM 1.37754729522807    -0.478401566279114  olivedrab4  Duodenum
HE1.RPM -1.84787050174421   3.29683025222076    hotpink3    Heart
HE2.RPM -1.57712374669721   3.72779965312866    hotpink3    Heart
HE3.RPM -1.62595902698841   3.4606008066362 hotpink3    Heart
HE4.RPM -0.907119493708492  3.17316852377154    hotpink3    Heart
HE5.RPM -1.65644593797311   3.82195960352629    hotpink3    Heart
IL1.RPM 1.44153778801558    -1.02823513385223   palegreen3  Ileum
IL2.RPM 1.4889578583487 -2.2804483432248    palegreen3  Ileum
IL3.RPM 1.91342848325147    -2.10569098957249   palegreen3  Ileum
IL4.RPM 0.962529810173936   -0.757115204974117  palegreen3  Ileum
JE1.RPM 1.93437797225407    -2.65674160788117   darkseagreen    Jejunum
JE2.RPM 2.06996643344844    -2.78640061968243   darkseagreen    Jejunum
JE3.RPM 1.62706829576533    -2.79624294732553   darkseagreen    Jejunum
JE4.RPM 1.0825326758516 -2.76470251848877   darkseagreen    Jejunum
JE5.RPM 1.38342677881686    -2.6755546386966    darkseagreen    Jejunum
KI1.RPM 0.967578089848615   1.67184647007406    orange3 Kidney
KI2.RPM 1.13378641637209    1.34124080803019    orange3 Kidney
KI3.RPM 1.37130716354727    1.80996835872441    orange3 Kidney
KI4.RPM 1.07772033561742    1.64994468114772    orange3 Kidney
KI5.RPM 1.0955496159798 2.0869739595772 orange3 Kidney
LI1.RPM 1.682084870402  -6.14052679905332   sienna  Liver
LI2.RPM 1.59906448215381    -6.29131805082633   sienna  Liver
LI3.RPM 1.45802709716468    -6.13448078364028   sienna  Liver
LI4.RPM 1.95665039443957    -6.5130493984287    sienna  Liver
LI5.RPM 1.80607410919614    -6.35273035030961   sienna  Liver
LU1.RPM -2.52491770797571   3.4865019812581 mediumpurple    Lung
LU2.RPM -2.86699310757743   3.34528752430189    mediumpurple    Lung
LU3.RPM -2.89232280631143   2.95189454920787    mediumpurple    Lung
LU4.RPM -2.66332768628549   3.09050672631981    mediumpurple    Lung
LU5.RPM -3.08812503849215   3.25327915431485    mediumpurple    Lung
PA1.RPM 1.29849330321564    -5.33710072865804   dodgerblue  Pancreas
PA2.RPM 1.19873085339097    -5.26535178376946   dodgerblue  Pancreas
PA3.RPM 1.11108191265227    -5.14709232997355   dodgerblue  Pancreas
PA5.RPM 0.895423334114921   -4.88663713272289   dodgerblue  Pancreas
PL1.RPM -1.06236761107225   3.49621079235936    red3    Blood
PL2.RPM -1.07888887772428   3.04101229356896    red3    Blood
PL3.RPM -0.844686506146655  3.23004986615368    red3    Blood
PL5.RPM -0.720030063721917  3.49005127885431    red3    Blood
SKI.RPM 0.199109542570694   2.44218482056362    pink2   Skin
SM1.RPM 0.563134748949276   2.02657901642232    plum    Muscle
SM2.RPM 0.340223402531866   2.27754829463276    plum    Muscle
SM3.RPM 0.770024511959072   1.97953000238431    plum    Muscle
```

And the following ggplot2 code:

```r
ggplot(Cat_urine, aes(x=UMAP1, y=UMAP2, color=colors)) + 
  geom_point(size=5) + 
  scale_color_manual(labels = c("Urine","Brain", "Colon", "Duodenum", "Jejunum", "Ileum", "Plasma", "Heart", "Skeletal muscle", "Skin",
                                "Kidney", "Liver", "Lungs", "Pancreas", "Urine"),
                     values = c("yellow2","darkgrey", "forestgreen", "olivedrab4", "palegreen3", "darkseagreen", "red3", "hotpink3", "plum", "pink2",
                                "orange3", "sienna", "mediumpurple", "dodgerblue")) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=5))) + 
  ylim(c(-7,5)) + xlim(c(-5,2.5)) + guides(shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 4))) +
  theme_bw() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=10), axis.title=element_text(size=12), 
                     axis.text.y =element_text(size=10),plot.margin = margin(1, 0.5, 0.5, 1, "cm")) + 
  xlab("\nComponent 1") + ylab("Component 2\n") +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.1, 0.33), legend.title = element_blank(),
                                                         legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = "black"))
```

Which generates this figure:

[image: UMAP plot]

I would like to divide the legend in two columns of 7 elements each. I have tried with `guides(fill=guide_legend(ncol=2))` but it did not modify anything. Maybe I put it in the wrong place or it might be another way to achieve that. Could anyone help?

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never define `fill=` as an aesthetic; use `guides(color=...)` instead.

Note: with this sample data, I needed to add another color to the `scale_color_manual`; it shouldn't be necessary with your real data. The only change I'm adding to your code is one argument to `guides`.

```r
ggplot(Cat_urine, aes(x=UMAP1, y=UMAP2, color=colors)) + 
  geom_point(size=5) + 
  scale_color_manual(labels = c("Urine","Brain", "Colon", "Duodenum", "Jejunum", "Ileum", "Plasma", "Heart", "Skeletal muscle", "Skin",
                                "Kidney", "Liver", "Lungs", "Pancreas", "Urine"),
                     values = c("yellow2","darkgrey", "forestgreen", "olivedrab4", "palegreen3", "darkseagreen", "red3", "hotpink3", "plum", "pink2",
                                "orange3", "sienna", "mediumpurple", "dodgerblue", "black")) +
  guides(
    colour = guide_legend(ncol = 2, override.aes = list(size=5))
##  ^^^^^^                ^^^^^^^^   these are the changes
  ) + 
  ylim(c(-7,5)) + xlim(c(-5,2.5)) + guides(shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 4))) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=10), axis.title=element_text(size=12), 
        axis.text.y =element_text(size=10),plot.margin = margin(1, 0.5, 0.5, 1, "cm")) + 
  xlab("\nComponent 1") +
  ylab("Component 2\n") +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.1, 0.33), legend.title = element_blank(), 
        legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = "black"))
```

[image]

Granted, you'll need to adjust the legend location ...

Comment: There was an error in one row defining colors. I corrected it. But now I was able to reproduce what I wanted. Many thanks.